# Angular 2 Http polling not delivering errors

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular2-http

I am trying to poll a REST API to update a data table which is working fine with the following code:

```
pollData(url, interval) {
  return Rx.Observable.interval(interval)
    .mergeMap(() => this.http.get(url));
}

// get data
this.dataService.pollData(this.url, this.updateInterval)
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log(data),
                err => console.log(err),
                () => console.log('done'));
```

The problem is that error and complete never get called. Any suggestions to get this working with onError and onCompete would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the `onComplete` call on the observer, it will be effected only when the source observable finishes. This means when the observable returned by `pollData` completes. As you are currently polling with no exit condition, then naturally your observable never completes.

To have this observable complete, you need to come up with an exit condition :

- timeout (for instance, poll for X seconds, then stop polling)
- number of polls
- pollData-based condition (for instance, if no changes detected after X consecutive polling)
- external completion signal
- any other condition which makes sense to your use case

All these conditions are easy to implement with RxJS through they will require you to update the code of the `pollData` function.

For instance for the external completion signal, you could write :

```
// defining somewhere the subject for signalling end of polling
stopPollingS = new Rx.Subject();

// somehow pass this subject as a parameter of the polling function
pollData(url, interval, stopPollingS) {
return Rx.Observable
         .interval(interval)
         .mergeMap(() => this.http.get(url))
         .takeUntil(stopPollingS);
}

// somewhere in your code when you want to stop polling
stopPollingS.onNext(true);
```

About the `onError` call on the observer, , I am not sure I get what is happening. Have you tried provoking an error and check the `onError` handler of your observer is indeed called? If there is no error, it is quite obvious that the `onError` will not be called.

Comment: Ive read up a little more about rxjs and what you said about oncomplete is fine but im still not getting the error coming through to my subscriber. When I implement http without interval and trigger a http 500 the error comes through but when it is wrapped in interval it doesnt

Comment: Can you post both jsfiddle so the behaviour can be reproduced?

Comment: I realised that the code that I posted was different to what I was testing, is missing .retry(). `pollData(url, interval) {
  return Rx.Observable.interval(interval)
    .mergeMap(() => this.http.get(url).retry());
}`
Ive since come to understand that the retry must be consuming the error hence the reason the subscriber is not receiving it. Thanks a lot for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone was wanting to know how I went about solving this problem and implemented the functionality that was required. Basically I just needed to wrap the observable in another and return the error as a data.

```
initiatePolling(url, interval) {

    var http = this.http;

    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {

        // initial request (no delay)
        requestData();
        var timerId = setInterval(requestData, interval);

        function requestData() {
            var subscription = http.get(url).timeout(20000)
                .subscribe(
                    result => {
                        observer.next(result);
                        subscription.unsubscribe();
                    },
                    err => {
                        observer.next(err);
                        subscription.unsubscribe();
                    },
                    () => {
                        subscription.unsubscribe();
                    });
        }

        return function () {
            observer.complete();
            window.clearInterval(timerId);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ok I figured it out `var x = this.initiatePolling(...)` then `x.subscribe((data)=>{...})`

Comment: I don't 100% understand that code but I'm new to RxJS, what I can tell, it does what I was looking for, if I could upvote 2x I would. Thanks. Would be just nice to refine this answer to include usage of initiatePolling